# Bring Edit with focus on a row newly added by clicking "Add Row" button in ui-grid of Angularjs

Tags: angular-ui-grid

While clicking add row button, it should add a new row in ui-grid and need to bring edit focus for all the column of the particular newly added row.

[Preview in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vgWWiKc6r6uem9g8sAAE?p=preview)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav></div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addUser()">Add row</button>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your addUser() function add this

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}
```

Unfortunately (due to a ui-grid limitation I cannot work around), you need to create an empty row in your initial data collection.

```
{
    "firstName": "Nancy",
    "lastName": "Waters",
    "company": "Fuelton",
    "employed": false
},
{
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "company": null,
    "employed": null
}
```

Then push() instead of unshift() to the second last row...

```
$scope.gridOptions.data.push(_model);
$scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus($scope.gridOptions.data[$scope.gridOptions.data.length - 2], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0]);
```

This works in your plunker, but you will need to handle (ignore) the empty row in your server, depending on how you are saving or processing the data in the grid.

Comment: @s-baggy Thanks for your replay. I checked with your sample in plunker. This is i want, but after tabbing cursor focused on next row. are you checked that issues. when i click tab cursor should focus to next column at the same row.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember this problem. In the end, I found it easier just to create a whole bunch of empty rows that the user could tab through, but I've edited my answer to suit. I hope it's OK if the new row appears at the bottom of the list?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback S. Baggy. We want the new row should appear in the top of the list. This is only issue, other than that we don't have any issues as of now. That is Cell navigation. Is there any way to solve the cell navigation issue or its not possible... Pls advice...

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do that. It is also the reason I had to add that redundant empty row to get it to work at all - something about the grid row index after adding the empty item to the data array. It might be worth looking around (or posting to) the ui-grid GitHub issues list, to see if this is being worked on. You could also try some sorting hacks to get what you want?

Comment: Thank you baggy for your advice. I will try to find out the issue.

Comment: Hi Baggy, We got Solution for Cell Navigation Issue. The Solution is: setTimeout(function() {        $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus($scope.gridOptions.data[0],$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0]);
}, 100);